# vue-cli - cannot build for development mode

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I have a .env file in my project

```
-public
-src
-.env.development.local
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "my-website",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "scripts": {
      "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
      "build": "vue-cli-service build --mode development",
      "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
    }
  }
```

When I run `npm run build` for the first time, it works.

When I run it after that, it shows error:

```
my-website@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build --mode development`
```

When I dig into the logs

```
13 verbose stack Error: my-website@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build --mode development`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
```

After I delete the `public` folder, it suddenly works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I update the `outputDir` from `public` to `build`, it works.

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  outputDir : 'build',
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There should be more log output which would be helpfull.

Based on your error maybe this helps:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3420

also try deleting your package-lock file and run npm i again
after that it hopefully works

Comment: please check my update above